# How do i install Ap-Hotspot in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: wireless, 14.04, hot-spot

When I enter the command:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
```

It gives this message

```
"Cannot add PPA: 'ppa"nilarimogard/webupd8'
 Please check that the PPA name and format is correct"
```

How do I proceed?

Answer (score 2):

Based on the output, you have a `"` in place of a `:` in the command.

The command you entered looks like this, likely:
`sudo add-apt-repository ppa"nilarimogard/webupd8`

... instead of this:
`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8`

Make sure the command you're using is the second one.

Comment: That was I was thinking too. Keyboards have different layout settings which might cause the `:` key to produce `"` as output.